# How to Include cordova mfilechooser plugin

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build

I am using Phonegap build service to build my hybrid app. I wonder how to include the following plugin in my config.xml:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/am.armsoft.mfilechooser

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can not use plugins which are not listed under plugins in [Phonegap build plugins](https://build.phonegap.com/plugins). Try this plugin intead. [FileChooser Cordova plugin for Android](https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/1986)

Answer (score 0):

@Nijil 
**Correction** on the repository, for now plugins need to come from the NPM repository. You can use the [Cordova Plugin Repository interface](http://cordova.apache.org/plugins/). The old repository will go away or change.

SEE: [Deprecation of Public Plugins on PhoneGap Build](http://phonegap.com/blog/2015/09/04/public-plugin-deprecation-on-build) - 04 Sep 2015

@user650922,
For directions on how to include a plugin, Start with the [documentation](http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/#googtrans%28en%29) then look for *Configuring->[Plugins](http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/configuring_plugins.md.html#Plugins)*

A typical plugin would be:

`<plugin name="cordova-plugin-example" spec="2.2.1" />`

in your case, it would like like this:

`<plugin name="am.armsoft.mfilechooser" source="npm" spec="1.0.4 " />`

`source="npm"` is *option* when using `<plugin (...) />`, but *required* when using `<gap:plugin (...) />`

Additional information is available in the [documentation](http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/configuring_plugins.md.html#Plugins) and a [recent blog post](http://phonegap.com/blog/phonegap-build)